# Why are Elasticsearch Scan/Scroll results so different?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm performing a scan/scroll to remap an index in my cluster (v2.4.3) and I'm having trouble understanding the results. In the head plugin my original index has this size/doc count:

**size: 1.74Gi (3.49Gi)**

**docs: 708,108 (1,416,216)**

If I perform a _reindex command on this index I get a new index with the same number of docs and the same size.

But if I perform a scan/scroll to copy the index I end up with may more records in my new index. I'm in the middle of the process right now and here is the current state of the new index:

**size: 1.81Gi (3.61Gi)**

**docs: 6,492,180 (12,981,180)**

Why are there so many more documents in the new index versus the old one? The mapping file declares 13 nested objects but I did not change the number of nested objects between the two indices.

Here is my scan/scroll code:

```
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("nas")
            .addSort(SortParseElement.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
            .setScroll(new TimeValue(120000))
            .setQuery(matchAllQuery())
            .setSize(pageable.getPageSize()).execute().actionGet();

    while (true) {
        if (response.getHits().getHits().length <= 0) break; //break out of the loop if failed

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<IndexQuery> indexQueries = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(response.getHits().getHits()).forEach(hit -> {
            NasProduct nasProduct = null;
            try {
                nasProduct = objectMapper.readValue(hit.getSourceAsString(), NasProduct.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Problem parsing nasProductJson json: || " + hit.getSourceAsString() + " ||", e);
            }
            if (nasProduct != null) {
                IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder()
                        .withObject(nasProduct)
                        .withId(nasProduct.getProductKey())
                        .withIndexName(name)
                        .withType("product")
                        .build();
                indexQueries.add(indexQuery);
            }
        });
        elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(indexQueries);
        logger.info("Index updated update count: " + indexQueries.size() + " duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");

        response = client.prepareSearchScroll(response.getScrollId())
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(120000))
                .execute().actionGet();
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/head-shows-incorrect-docs-count-if-nested-type-field-is-defined-in-mapping/23270/4) may help you to find the answer.

Comment: That number matches the original doc count. Thanks!

Comment: Glad! it helped you!